# How do I store an array into an element of ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
Robentry [] Rb = new Robentry[robNum];
```

How can I store `Rb` into an `ArrayList<E> Rt`, so that `Rt.get(0) == Rb` is `true`. I do not know how to define `E` in the `ArrayList<E>`.

**Edit:**

If I use :

```
Robentry [] Rb = new Robentry[robNum];
List<Robentry []> Rt = new  ArrayList<Robentry []>();
// initialize Rb
//...
// 
Rt.add(Rb);
```

If I change `Rb[0]`, `Rt.get(0)[0]` is also changed. So how can I store the content of `Rb` into `Rt` so that `Rt` is independent of `Rb`?

Comment: There are plenty of examples of this available. I mean, you're not showing any research effort.

Comment: Well, E is a type.  I'd assume then that you want an `ArrayList<RobEntry[]>`, since Rb is of type `RobEntry[]`.

Comment: `Rt.add(Rb.clone());` for your second problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your modified question, you probably want

```
Rt.add(Rb.clone());
```

or

```
Rt.add(Arrays.copyOf(Rb, Rb.length));
```

Array references are passed around by value, so you have to do an explicit copy if you want the arrays to be independent of one another.

Answer (score 7):

`ArrayList<Robentry[]> arrList` sounds like what you want.

This means `arrList` is a `List` (or `ArrayList`) of `Robentry[]`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Type Robentry[] to a List. like -

```
List<Robentry []> list = new ArrayList<Robentry []>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare and use the `List` of type `Robentry[]` as below:

```
    //Declare a list of type Robentry[] 
    List<Robentry[]> list = new ArrayList<Robentry []>();
    //add the rb to the list
    list.add(Rb);

    //compare the list element with Rb
    System.out.println(list.get(0)==Rb);//should print true
```

Please note: `==` is fine in above example since list element is same as Rb, otherwise `equals` method is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ArrayList<Robentry> Rt=(ArrayList<Robentry>) Arrays.asList(Rb);
```

or in your ways,

```
ArrayList<Robentry[]> Rt=new ArrayList<Robentry[]>();
rt.add(Rb);
```

This is called Generics,was made to ensure that the variable should contain only specific types.See this for official [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html).